# How is remove min on a sorted array implementation of a priority Queue constant time?

Tags: big-o, priority-queue

As per this lecture from uc Berkley[CS61B lecture 16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIXCafOhMro&list=PL1Yv8vrhoiln0oHlQV6dbj_beXNH79S3e&index=16), if a priority queue is implemented as a sorted array, the remove min is constant time.
[image: Priority queue running times]

If you just remove the element at the zeroth index, then wouldn't you have to move all the items over to the left? In which case wouldnt it be theta of n? Else find min will not be constant time.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the heap storage is implemented.  There are certainly array implementations that do not require shuffling.  I could just move the head pointer up one.

Comment: If you sort it in descending order then *removeMin* is O(1): just lop off the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a priority queue as a sorted array, there are two different ways to ensure that *removeMin* is an O(1) operation.

If the array is sorted in ascending order, then the smallest element is at the front of the array. In this case you maintain an index that tells you where the beginning of the queue is. When you first build it, then of course the index is at the front of the array (`a[0]` or `a[1]`, depending on your choice of language). When you want to remove the smallest element, you return the item at `a[idx]`, and then increment `idx`.

Any time you insert an item you write the code to move everything up to the front of the array again and reset `idx` to 0 (or 1, as appropriate).

The other way is to maintain the array in descending order. The smallest element is the last element of the array. You already have to keep track of how many elements are in the array. So you have an index, call it `ixEnd`. When you want to remove the smallest element, you return `a[ixEnd]`, and subtract 1 from `ixEnd`.

Either way, insertion is O(n) and `removeMin` is O(1).